# Difficulties to find equation in Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find equation (picture attached) in Cartesian form by using  trigonometry which I want to plot in Matlab.

[image]

I have solved 4 points which are

\begin{align}(x_1=28.03&, y_1=19)\\
 (x_2=28.03+3.9&, y_2=y_1)\\
(x_3=x2&, y_3=y_1+3.1)\\
 (x_4=x_3+19\cos(\pi/2)&, y_4=y_3+19\sin(\pi/2)) \end{align}

but cant understand last two points $(x_5,y_5)$ and $(x_6,y_6)$. I have plotted first four points and it was perfect. The last two points I have tried but seems hard to me.

Would anyone please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: There is no picture to be seen.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I attached picture. dont know how can i add it?

Comment: In the edit window, click on the 6th icon (looks like a mountain).

Comment: I've added the image and typed out your equations in MathJax

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: The figure you're apparently trying to draw is impossible. The distance from $(x_4,y_4)$ to $(x_6,y_6)$ is greater than $21.9.$ It might help if you would explain, one step at a time, why each length and angle in the picture should be what you showed in the picture.

Comment: Thank  you so much. i solved the problem.